# how to get all regular files and long list with only one command

Tags: linux

I want to list all regular files in my current directory and have the byte size included in my output.

Basically, "ls -l" but only with regular files. I want to do this with only one utility, and my current script uses two utilities:

`find -type f -exec ls -l {} \;`

How can I fix this to use only one utility?

Comment: Is there any concrete reason for that?

Comment: @Jorengarenar i am curious

Comment: `find -type f -printf "%p %s\n"`